# How many bingo card combinations are there?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Bingo cards have $5$ rows and $5$ columns. The column names are **B,I,N,G,O.** Each column has $15$ possible numbers to choose from $1-15$ for $B$, $16-30$ for $I$, $31-45$ for $N$, and so forth.

The third space on the $N$ is 'daubed' or blocked out, so the card only has $24$ numbers.

I don't think $75$ choose $24$ is right. Is $15$ choose $5$ times $4$ plus $15$ choose $4$ (because of the $N$ column) the correct answer$?$ (Which I calculate to $13377$ combinations, which seems too small.)

Comment: Edit: read the question wrong, sorry!

Comment: According to the answer, below, and the rate at which games are played on the video games my company produces, it would take  6,468,170,870,637,260,000 years to play through all the cards if each one was generated only once. 6.5 million trillion years. Ain't nobody got time for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are four complete columns of 5 and one with only 4 numbers. For column 1 there are: $$5! {15 \choose 5}$$ Since there are 5 numbers out of a possible 15 used in the column and these can be permuted in any order (in 5! ways). This also holds for the other 3 complete columns. The same method works for the column of 4 giving instead: $$4! {15 \choose 4} $$

Therefore the total answer is: $$ \left (5! {15 \choose 5} \right)^4 4! {15 \choose 4} = 552446474061128648601600000 $$

Comment: Note this is assuming that it matters which box the numbers go in - I've never played bingo so don't know if this matters!

Comment: It does matter. The answer is amazingly large o.O

Comment: In redoing it I came up with 81 trillion bingo cards, which is a lot less than just a simple random 75 choose 24 combinations. Basically my method but using multiplication.

Comment: Redid my math and my number agrees for the number of permutions. We need those because the same numbers per column can be rearranged and produce a different card. The same ball call will produce different results on the two cards.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is ${15\choose5}^4\cdot{15\choose4}$.

Columns B, I, N, G and O are independent, so the Fundamental Counting Principle applies. You multiply the number of choices for each column.

Edit: Oops! @Zestylemonzi is correct. I should have used permutations, not combinations. The answer should be $({}_{15}P_{5})^4\cdot({}_{15}P_{4})$.

Answer (score 1):

It is not Permutations, because the order does not matter. It is in fact Combinations. $$ {15 \choose 5}{15 \choose 5 }{ 15 \choose 4}{15 \choose 5}{15 \choose 5} = 1.11\cdot10^{17} $$

Comment: The order does matter. Two players with the same numbers but in different order will score differently off the same ball call sequence.

Comment: Order matters when attempting patterns (e.g. horizontal line, vertical line, diagonal and all the special bingo patterns common to 75 number bingo in North America). In a full blackout bingo order of the numbers in the columns does not matter. Other regions (such as those that use 100 balls) more often play bingo as a blackout or full card bingo (in my experience).

Answer (score 1):

It is a combination in respect to "full-card"  bingo, only.  However, not every game of Bingo is played as full-card.  Other variations I have played include "X", "Crazy T", "Crazy L", "Butterfly", and then straight line/4 corners.  With regard to those games, the order of the numbers certainly does matter, so it is a permuation.  Therefore, it is (15P5)^4 X 15P4.  According to wikipedia's Bingo page, it is 552,446,474,061,128,648,601,600,000.  I tried solving this in Excel, and had an answer less accurate as it seems Excel has a max of 15 significant digits.  It does seem that wikipedia's answer is accurate.  15P5=360,360 and 15P4=32,760.  When you multiply 360,360^4 x 32,760, your answer will end with 5 zeros.

In regards to full-card bingo, where the order does not matter, then we have (15C5)^4 x 15C4, which is 111,007,923,832,370,565.

Comment: Try Wolfram Alpha when you have big calcs to do. It seems much more accurate. Good points. Our bingo games are on slot machines so we have a lot of patterns we look for to derive the prizes. The hot dog pattern, for example, is row 2: I N G, Row 3: B I G O, and Row 4: I N G. You have to hit it in a certain number of balls, and the balls are always pulled in BINGO order.

Answer (score 1):

@Zestlyemonzi has correctly given the number of possible Bingo cards. Note, however, that Bingo cards have one axis of symmetry; if you reverse the order of the numbers in each column, the card will produce the same results in a standard game (not in all variants). Therefore, for a standard game, the number of *distinct* Bingo cards is 552446474061128648601600000 / 2 = 276223237030564324300800000.

Comment: I think you can flip 3 different ways, Horizontal, Vertical, and both and still get the same horizontal, vertical and diagonal patterns. However in casino bingo they consider, further, the number of balls called in the ball call and include esoteric, non-flippable patterns. That said, extra bonus points for you!

Answer (score -1):

Since no number is ever repeated on a bingo card under the 'B' the first position has 15 possibilities the second position has 14 the third position has 13 and so on so the correct equation would be 15 * 14 * 13 * 12 * 11 * 4 because B, I, G and O each have that number of possibilities (or 360,360) and under the N where there is a free space it would be 15 * 14 * 13 * 12 (or  32760) 
(360.360 × 4) + 32,760 = 1,474,200 possibilities.